# Calling a templatized member function: Help me understand a code snippet from another StackOverflow posting

Tags: c++, templates

In reference to [May pointer to members circumvent the access level of a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907328/may-pointer-to-members-circumvent-the-access-level-of-a-member), I would like to understand the code snippet in that question.

I will paste the code snippet here.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Tag, typename Tag::type M>
struct Rob { 
  friend typename Tag::type get(Tag) {
    return M;
  }
};

// use
struct A {
  A(int a):a(a) { }
private:
  int a;
};

// tag used to access A::a
struct A_f { 
  typedef int A::*type;
  friend type get(A_f);
};

template struct Rob<A_f, &A::a>;

int main() {
  A a(42);
  std::cout << "proof: " << a.*get(A_f()) << std::endl;
}
```

Among a few questions, I highlight a single question here that may crack open the rest.

I do not understand the following statement in the `main` function:

```
a.*get(A_f())
```

I *do* understand (I think) that `get(A_F())` returns a pointer to `a.a`.  However, I do not understand the `get()` function.  In what struct is this actually defined?  How is it being accessed in that struct?

I have two secondary questions that may be answered if the above question is answered, but I will place them here.  First, in the definition of `Rob`, the `friend` keyword is being used in front of the function `get` that is being defined, as well as declared.  I thought that the `friend` keyword can only be used in front of a function *declaration* to indicate that a function defined *elsewhere* has access to the private/protected members of the class.  Can someone explain?

Second, I do not understand the line `template struct Rob<A_f, &A::a>;`.  I do not understand the use of the `template` keyword without `<...>`, and I do not understand why there is no template definition - this seems to be some sort of forward declaration.  Can someone explain?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I do not understand the `get()` function. In what struct is this actually defined? How is it being accessed in that struct?

First thing first: the function`get()` is a friend of both `A` and `Rob` class template. It is not a member function of any class. It is rather a free function.

Now, where exactly is this *free* function defined? Well it is *defined* in `Rob` class template, and at the same time it is declared as `friend` of `Rob` class template.

> I thought that the friend keyword can only be used in front of a function declaration to indicate that a function defined elsewhere has access to the private/protected members of the class. Can someone explain?

Yes it can be declared `friend` of a class, without defining it inside the class. It can **also** be *defined* inside a class and at the same time can be declared `friend` of that class. In your case, it is actually defined in the class itself.

> Second, I do not understand the line `template struct Rob<A_f, &A::a>;`.

That is called [explicit instantiation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc16explicit_instantiation.htm) of the class template with the given tempate arguments. You can see many other syntax to explicitly instantiate a template here (well if it is a *function template*):

- [C++ Template Specialization and Instantiation Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323530/c-templates-specialization-syntax)

Comment: Thank you.  I have looked carefully at the link and nested links you provided.  I'm close to understanding this.  Can you please tell me how you know, from the syntax, that `template struct Rob<A_f, &A::a>;` is an instantiation, and not the declaration for a template specialization?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Because I know the syntaxes of both template specialization and template explicit instantiation. Their syntaxes are not same; they're different, so I know which is which.

Comment: Nawaz - a thoroughly rude response.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: That is not rude. If that is rude, then  lets say this: how do you know that `int i;` is a declaration of variable `i`? or Lets say, how do you know that `i` is a variable in the syntax `int i;`, and how do you know that `i` is not a function? Please answer my questions :-)

Comment: `i` is a variable in `int i;` because the `int` keyword prepends it.  Second, `i` is a variable in `int i;` because `i` appears after the built-in type keyword `int`.  Third, `i` is not a function because there are no parentheses that follow `i` in the statement `int i;`.  Perhaps now you could answer my question, which is not as trivial?  Thanks.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: An explicit specialization begins with `template<>`, and an explicit instantiation just begins with `template`.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: `int` keyword prepends it, so what is great about that? How exactly do you know that if that is really a variable?

Comment: @Nawaz: Short is all I needed - not a full discussion, but something to point the way.  Please stop acting rudely.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: That is TOO JUDGEMENTAL. All I'm trying to make you realize that there is nothing rude in my first comment, because I know that you would answer my question, saying *"because I know that"*, and there is nothing rude in saying that.