# call Private function in c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling private method in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873138/calling-private-method-in-c)

I have a DLL, and in that DLL they exposed some functions but one of them is private. The function is `C_MORPHO_Device::InitUsbDevicesNameEnum(PUL  o_pul_NbUsbDevice)`.

How can I call this `InitUsbDevicesNameEnum` function in my application?

Comment: Also unless the library is badly designed.. you should not need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the private method also exported? I doubt it (why would they export a private method?). But if it is exported, you can use the **dumpbin /exports** command to see the decorated method name, then use GetProcAddress to get a function pointer to the method and call on an instance of the class. Something like:

```
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(L"thedll.dll");
(C_MORPHO_Device::*pMethod)(PUL) = reinterpret_cast<(C_MORPHO_Device::*)(PUL)>(GetProcAddress(hModule, L"InitUsbDevicesNameEnum@_ABunchOfSymbolsHere"));

C_MORPHO_Device device;
(device.*pMethod)(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Simply do not do that.** The library author has made the function private, so you shall not call it. Read the documentation to find out which functions you are intended to call.

Answer (score 1):

*Private method should be private* to others. Why you need to call a private method, if the made at as private ?. They have made like this for some reason.

You can check any of other `public` or `friend` function in that calling this method `InitUsbDevicesNameEnum`. But that is not a good way of accessing private methods

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way to instantiate the class and call its private method.