# How to compile a C++ code in gcc (g++) to see the name mangling on overloaded functions?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have overloaded functions like:

```
void f(int)
void f(int, int)
void f(int, float)
```

How to compile it, so that i can see the mangled output?
Something like:

```
void f(int) should show: ?f@@YAXH@Z(int)
```

Like for example, to see pre-processor output we use `-E`, assembler output `-s`, what is it for name mangled output?

P.S: Platform is Linux

EDIT:

**And by the answers here we go:**

```
void func(int);
void func(int, int);
void func(void);
void func(char);

[root@localhost ~]# cat a.map | grep func
                0x0804881a                _Z4funcc
                0x08048790                _Z4funcv
                0x080487be                _Z4funcii
                0x080487ec                _Z4funci
```

Comment: Call the functions without implementing them, the linker will be kind enough to tell you the mangled name in the error message. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For GCC try using:

```
-Xlinker -Map=output.map
```

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

This will generate a map file which will have all of the mangled symbol names.

And for MSVC:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2(v=vs.80).aspx

This will generate something such as:

```
0002:00094190       ??0SerializationException@EM@@QAE@ABV01@@Z 10148190 f i y:foo.obj
```

Comment: Great answer. Yours and chrisaycock both serve the purpose, but since i asked from the gcc perspective, so yours is the one i should choose. Thanks :-)

Comment: @kingsmasher1 I'm curious as to why mine doesn't "serve the purpose".

Answer (score 5):

In Linux, I can see the names of all symbols via `nm`. For example:

```
$ nm a.out | grep pthread
                 w pthread_cancel@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U pthread_key_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U pthread_key_delete@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Answer (score 3):

The `-S` option tells GCC to only compile but not assemble a function. I. e., it will output human-readable assembly text, in which you'll be able to see the function names. Run it through `c++filt` so that you can associate the mangled names with the unmangled ones.

Comment: Once you've got the assembler, `c++filt myProg.s | diff - myProg.s` should give the information you need.

Comment: Your answer serves the purpose too, and thanks for letting us know an alternate way to achieve the same goal, but i can accept only 1 answer at a time (unfortunately), and since i asked the question from gcc perspective, so the other one was a closer match.